# How to show real time in the html web page?

Tags: jquery

HI in my webpage, I've got 3 different clocks made by flash. All the flash clocks are working. Now i need to set the real time to all these 3 clocks. Do you have any idea to show the real clock to the html web page using javascript or jquery? i need to show the clocks for London, Newyork and New delhi. Is it possible?

This flash clocks have the parameters to set the times like this:

```
{thisH:myH + 2,thisM:myM + 2,thisS:myS + 2};
```

So, do I just need to pass the real times to this variables.  How can i get 3 different times from any server? Any one help me?

Comment: i think little more details need to be added there

Comment: Do you plan to use a script system with ajax, or is jquery only?

Comment: if i get jquery then that's better. if there is no chance i am ready to use ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use earthtools.org . They have a free web service that provides you with all the time data you might want for any place on earth.

http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone

this is an example of the data for NY:
http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/40.71417/-74.00639

will return:

```
<timezone xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1.xsd">
  <version>1.1</version>
  <location>
    <latitude>40.71417</latitude>
    <longitude>-74.00639</longitude>
  </location>
  <offset>-5</offset>
  <suffix>R</suffix>
  <localtime>24 May 2011 06:05:51</localtime>
  <isotime>2011-05-24 06:05:51 -0500</isotime>
  <utctime>2011-05-24 11:05:51</utctime>
  <dst>Unknown</dst>
</timezone>
```

You can consume the service easily with jQuery

Comment: where can i get the latitude and longitude of cities?

Comment: do yo have any example script to retrieve data from this url using jquery?

Comment: this http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery can probably help you out

Comment: i am using this, but i dint get any result :

Comment: $(document).ready(function (){
  $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/51.5001524/-0.1262362",
    dataType : "xml",
    success : function (data){
      alert(data);
     }
   })
 })

Comment: Actually, there is indeed a problem with that... you can't load ajax from 3rd party domain in javascript... you might need to do a proxy at your server that will fetch the data for you...